# PHP XML find "searching" node and create new node after "searching node"

Tags: php, xml

i need some help from you :

loading XML from a file.
I'm also loading data from a CSV file.
I have 2 columns in CSv:

1. ID
2. Number

I'm looking for the ID from the CSV in the XML file.

I can find you, everything works.
However, I need to edit the XML as follows:

1. If you find an  element in the XML whose ID is contains an ID value from a CSV file, copy this  element as many times as the value is in the CSV (column number).

Here is my code.

```
<?php

    $file = 'doc.xml';
    
    if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
        echo "failed to copy";
    }

    $fh = fopen("data.csv", "r");
    $csvData = array();
    
    //Loop through the rows in our CSV file and add them to
    //the PHP array that we created above.
    while (($row = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $csvData[] = $row;
    }

    $length = count($csvData);

    if (file_exists('doc.xml')) {  
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('doc.xml');

        for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $searchedNode = $csvData[$i+1][0];
            $searchingMedia = $xml->xpath("/node/media/image[contains(@id,'$searchedNode')]");  

            
            foreach ($searchingMedia as $node) {
                $update = $node->addAttribute('count',$csvData[$i+1][1]);
            }
        }
    }
    $xml->asXml('doc_new.xml');

?>
```

CSV data :
[image]

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimplXML abstracts the XML nodes, so it is not the best API for direct node manipulations - use DOM.

You did not provide an example but from your code I would expect something like this:

```
$data = [
    [
        '42', '6'      
    ]    
];

$xml = <<<'XML'
<root>
  <node>
    <media>
      <image id="42"/>
    </media>
  </node>
</root>
XML;
```

Then it is fairly straightforward:

```
// bootstrap the DOM
$document = new DOMDocument();
// let the parser ignore whitespace nodes (indents)
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$document->loadXML($xml);
// DOM has a spearate object for Xpath
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// iterate the CSV data
foreach ($data as $row) {
    // looking for "image" elements with a specific id attribute
    $expression = sprintf(
        '//root/node/media/image[@id="%s"]', 
        $row[0]
    );
    // iterate the found image nodes 
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $imageNode) {
        // "amount" times
        for ($i = 0, $c = (int)$row[1]; $i < $c; $i++) {
            // clone the "image" element and insert clone after it
            $imageNode->after(
                $newNode = $imageNode->cloneNode(TRUE)
            ); 
            // modify the clone 
            $newNode->textContent = 'Inserted Node #'.$i;
        }
    }
}

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <node>
    <media>
      <image id="42"/>
      <image id="42">Inserted Node #5</image>
      <image id="42">Inserted Node #4</image>
      <image id="42">Inserted Node #3</image>
      <image id="42">Inserted Node #2</image>
      <image id="42">Inserted Node #1</image>
      <image id="42">Inserted Node #0</image>
    </media>
  </node>
</root>
```

Comment: many thanks @ThW ...  "danke sehr"